# Incoherence between `AssociateTo`/`KeyDropFrom` and `DownValues`

Tags: associations

My version is 13.2 on Mac. When modifying association I find the following incoherences between `AssociateTo`/`KeyDropFrom` and `DownValues`. Consider the three examples:

**0. The expected example:**

```
assoc=<|a->1|>;
AssociateTo[assoc,b->1];
KeyDropFrom[assoc,a];
assoc
(*<|b->1|>*)
```

**1. `AssociateTo` and `DownValues`**

```
Clear@assoc2;
assoc2["string"]=<|a->1|>;
assoc2[1]=<|a->1|>;
assoc2[symbol]=<|a->1|>;
assoc2[]=<|a->1|>;
```

The following three give expected results

```
AssociateTo[assoc2["string"],b->1]
(*<|a->1,b->1|>*)
AssociateTo[assoc2[symbol],b->1]
(*<|a->1,b->1|>*)
AssociateTo[assoc2[1],b->1]
(*<|a->1,b->1|>*)
```

but the last one will not be evaluated,

```
AssociateTo[assoc2[],b->1]
(*AssociateTo[assoc2[],b->1]*)
assoc2[]
(*<|a->1|>*)
```

`KeyDropFrom` doesn't have this problem.

**2. `KeyDropFrom` and `DownValues` with nested `Association`**

```
Clear@assocNest;
assocNest[1]=<|a-><|b->1|>|>
```

`AssociateTo` can modify this nested association,

```
AssociateTo[assocNest[1][a],c->1]
(*<|a-><|b->1,c->1|>|>*)
```

but `KeyDropFrom` cannot

```
KeyDropFrom[assocNest[1][a],c]
(*Association::setps: <|a-><|b->1,c->1|>|> in the part assignment is not a symbol.*)
assocNest[1]
(*<|a-><|b->1,c->1|>|>*)
```

**Question:**

Are these bugs or documented behaviours? Are there simple workaround?